How to fix this issue of can't be accessed using static?
Error:

Instance member 'initSharedPreferences' can't be accessed using static
access.dartstatic_access_to_instance_member

class SharedPrefHelper {
  SharedPreferences? sharedPref;

  Future<void> initSharedPreferences() async {
    print("Running get instance");
    sharedPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
}

Future initiateAuthBloc() async {
    await SharedPrefHelper.initSharedPreferences(); 
  }

when I tried to access this methos got an above error,
How to fix it?

Can you also show the code in which you try to call the method?

Now I have added

You are statically calling a method that is not static. I suggest you read the documentation about classes. Specifically the part about static variables and methods

You have to define static before variable, Like this
  class SharedPrefHelper {
  static SharedPreferences? sharedPref;

  static Future<void> initSharedPreferences() async {
    print("Running get instance");
    sharedPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
}

Future<void> initiateAuthBloc() async {
  await SharedPrefHelper.initSharedPreferences();
}

